# Applying effects to Images in sequence

Tags: jquery, image, effects, fade

I started jQuery this morning (so I'm a noob) and it seemed promising at first but then this...

The idea is to fade in and fade out images one after another with a delay. But they all are faded in at the same time and then faded out. I want them to do that one after another.

Tried modifying the single `<img>` tag, then filling with html() a `<div>`, then this and couple other things. This might be a piece of cake but I just don't see it!

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">

    span.button{
        display:block;
        width:10px;
        border:1px solid;
        float:left;
        background:#eeeeee;
        padding:5px;
        margin:5px;
        font-weight:bold;
        color:#333333;
        cursor:pointer;
        border-radius:7px;
        border-color:#555555; 
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #777777;
    }

img.gImages{
    border:1px solid;
    border-left-color:#eeeeee;
    border-top-color:#eeeeee;
    border-right-color:#666666;
    border-bottom-color:#666666;
    border-radius:5px;
    height:300px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #777777;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var numOfimgs=3;
$(document).ready(function(){

function preloadImages(numOfimgs){
    var i=0;
    for(i=1; i<numOfimgs+1; i++){
        $("div").append('<img class="gImages" id="'+i+'slika" src="'+i+'.jpg" />');
        $("img#"+i+"slika").hide();
        $("div").append(i);
    }
}
preloadImages(numOfimgs);

function animateImage(imgId){
    $("img#"+imgId+"slika").fadeIn("slow");
    $("img#"+imgId+"slika").fadeOut("slow");
}

function startAnimation(){
var i=0;
for(i=1; i<numOfimgs+1; i++){
    animateImage(i);
    }
}

startAnimation();
});
</script> 
</head>

<body>
<div></div>
<span>below the div</span>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need to use the callback function for `fadeOut`: http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/#callback-function (You'll feel so much better if you try it yourself.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

```
function sequencedFade(imgIndex, numImages) {
    if(imgIndex <= numImages) {
        //... your other random stuff here
        $("#"+imgIndex+"slika").fadeOut('slow', function() { sequencedFade(imgIndex++, numImages) });
        //... more other random stuff
    }
}

sequencedFade(0, 3);
```

This uses the callback function of `fadeOut` which is executed upon animation completion.

### **http://jsfiddle.net/9KYqJ/**

Comment: Thank you guys, I'll try with the callback function and report back.

Comment: So you all had in mind the callback function which was helpful.

I used Adam Terlson's example, added "fadeIn()", "delay()" and then "else" to do the same thing as "if" but only passed 0 as argument to reset loop back on the 1st picture.

Comment: Oh, and iteration imgIndex++ didn't worked this way, for some reason, so I changed it to imgIndex+1 which does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

FadeIn and fadeOut image until you have fadein and fadeout all images

```
function animateImage(imgId){
     if($("img#"+imgId+"slika").length <> 0)
     {
         $("img#"+imgId+"slika").fadeIn("slow", function(){
              $("img#"+imgId+"slika").fadeOut("slow", function(){ animateImage(imgId + 1);});
         });
     }

}

function startAnimation(){

       animateImage(0);

}
```

And for your knowledge, I'm using the second parameter of fadeIn and fadeOut, it's the callback, do this function when  the animation is finish